# After Ubuntu install PC still boots straight to Windows XP

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 14.04

I have just installed Ubuntu on a machine running Windows XP. I selected the option to install alongside Windows. Everything seemed to go well. When it finished I removed the boot/install DVD and re-booted. The machine booted into Windows with no sign of Ubuntu.

I checked in the disk management tools and, sure enough, there is the partion created for Ubuntu but I can't find a way to get Ubuntu started.

I expected to get an option at boot up enabling me to select Windows or Ubuntu but that doesn't happen.

Sould I be looking for something else or is it likely that something has gone wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help/advice offered,

Simon.

Edit: I downloaded 14.04, I didn't do anything explicit to dual boot, I expected that to occur as part of the installation. I will check tose links.

Sorry if this is a duplicate ... if I knew what GRUB is and how it is related then I would have searched for it first honestly! I wouldn't expect others to do the hard work for me if I can find an answer:)

Another edit: Progress! There are two discs in this machine and it does appear that Ubuntu created some boot files on the secondary drive as opposed to the boot drive. I am now checking for a solution and will report it here as soon as I find one.

Thanks for the pointers,

Simon.

Last Edit: Fixed it! Thanks for all your help, I would not have found this on my own. The answer for me was to use this: http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/

Thanks everybody,

Simon.

Comment: which version are you working with 14.04 or 12.04?? how did you dual boot. I mean directly or using software's like EasyBCD?? and did you install grub ?? this might help if you read it <http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/02/how-to-dual-boot-windows-xp-and-linux.html>

Comment: @Creator remove `<` `>` markings from your link because it made it broken.

Comment: sorry for that I will do it .. and the link is http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/02/how-to-dual-boot-windows-xp-and-linux.html%3E

Comment: Anybody know how I mark this as solved? (I do feel silly asking this because I'm guessing that it's obvious!)